# How to split a string that is separated by comma, into multiple strings using Bash

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

I am creating a git-hub workflow using workflow_dispatch for my inputs data

```
workflow_dispatch:
     inputs:
      Browser:
          description: 'Select what browsers to use'     
          required: true
          default: 'Chrome'
```

And I got my setup job, where I take my workflow_dispatch data and trasfer them to json, so I can use it in my matrix

```
jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix-browser: ${{ steps.set-matrix-browser.outputs.matrix-browser }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - id: set-matrix-browser
      run: |
        testBro="${{ github.event.inputs.Browser }}"
        echo "::set-output name=matrix-browser::[\"${testBro}\"]"
        echo "[\"${testBro}\"]"
```

So, my question is:
If I got two or more browsers in my `github.event.inputs.Browser = "Chrome, Safari, Edge"`, who I can to split them, for each browser to be a separate string.

I want my output to look like this,

> ["Chrome", "Safari, "Edge"]

but instead I got this

> ["Chrome, Safari, Edge"]

Can you please suggest how I need to change this line of code?

```
echo "::set-output name=matrix-browser::[\"${testBro}\"]"
```

I've tried something like this:

```
echo "::set-output name=matrix-browser::[\"${testBro | tr "," "\n"}\"]"
```

Comment: Would appreciate an update to this that uses GITHUB_OUTPUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it

```
echo "::set-output name=matrix-browser::[\"${testBro//', '/\",\"}\"]"
```

Thanks everybody

Comment: Any idea what the new format would be with deprecated ::set-output??
Eg: "TIME_SINCE=$(some-command)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

Comment: set-output is being depricated soon. 
new version would be:

`echo "matrix-browser=[\"${testBro//', '/\",\"}\"]" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `testBro="Chrome,Safari,Edge"`

`echo [\"$testBro\"] |sed 's/,/\", \"/g'` 
 or for the full line 
 `echo "::set-output name=matrix-browser:: $(echo [\"$testBro\"] |sed 's/,/\", \"/g')"`

gives the output

`::set-output name=matrix-browser:: ["Chrome", "Safari", "Edge"]`

Comment: if testBro is a string and not an array you could use `echo $test | sed "s/,/ /g"|xargs  printf "\"%s\"," |sed -r 's/(.*),/\1 /'`

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. 
The value of `testBro` is `"Chrome, Safari, Edge"` .
And when I am using echo `"::set-output name=matrix-browser::[\"${testBro}\"]"`, the `testBro` value is `["Chrome, Safari, Edge"]`

But I need it to be `["Chrome", "Safari, "Edge"]`

Comment: I changed the answer

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but still I got the array with one string `["Chrome, Safari, Edge"]`

Comment: I figure it  echo `"::set-output name=matrix-browser::[\"${testBro//', '/\",\"}\"]"`
thanks